# API returning incorrect transactionsPerSession and transactionRevenue data when a custom filter pagepath added

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the API to get analytics data display, For that first I am checking data and parameters in this ga-dev-tool. have checked both ways in ga-dev-tool.

When I try without pagepath its works properly and I get data of transactionsPerSession and transactionRevenue.
But when I try with pagepath in the same way it's not working and giving 00 for all these 2 values.

https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/query-explorer/

https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/request-composer/

Here I have also attached images for result with query parameters :

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you want to get transection related data from API

Then You have to pass ga:landingPagePath

Instead of ga:pagePath in dimension Filter

Let me know if you still getting incorrect transactionsPerSession.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Google Analytics [Help Document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861)

> Not every metric can be combined with every dimension. Each dimension
> and metric has a scope: user-level, session-level, or hit-level. In
> most cases, it only makes sense to combine dimensions and metrics that
> share the same scope. For example, Sessions is a session-based metric
> so it can only be used with session-level dimensions like Source or
> City. It would not be logical to combine Sessions with a hit-level
> dimension like Page.

Hence, it makes sense to combine Pagepath with Pageviews but not with Transaction related metrics.

Comment: Thank you @dikesh
So you want to say that this filter base on page path will not work with Transaction related data like .
Can you please explain if I want  a Transaction related data based on page wise what will be the procedure
and just to inform me I am using the php v3/v4 api for this.

Comment: @MehulMakwana There is no relation of page with Transactions. You can use other Ecommerce dimensions like ga:transactionId, ga:daysToTransaction, ga:shoppingStage, etc. Checkout the [list of dimension and metrics](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) you can use for reporting, if you haven't.